# hotkey "I" for insert keyframes does not work in pose mode

Tags: animation, armature, keyframes

Hotkey "I" for inserting keyframes does not show up in pose mode although, I has not activate "keying set".  "I" works in object mode though.  Using Blender 2.8.

How can I fix this?

thx
[image]

Comment: maybe you've locked some of your tracks in the Dope Sheet? If it's not the case maybe share your armature: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: in the end I have to restore to factor setting, then it is fixed.  nothing I did fix the issue.  may be the key map is unstable for right click select?

Answer (score 1):

your mouse should be in the view port to add key frames , or else enable auto key framing